# Error while Passing Json string in scala using Curl

Tags: json, scala, curl, post

I am trying to post a json string using curl in scala. My curl command works fine if executed from linux box but throes an error(("message": "Must provide query string.",) always from scala.

my working curl command in linux:

```
 curl http://laptpad1811:5000/graphql -H "Content-Type: application/json"  
    -X POST -d '{"query":"mutation 
    CreateFileReceivedEvent($createFileReceivedEventInput: 
    CreateFleReceivedEventInput!) {  createFileReceivedEvent(input: 
    $createFileReceivedEventInput) {    clientMutationId  }}","variables":
    {"createFileReceivedEventInput":
    {"clientMutationId":"Test","fileReceivedEvent":{"file":
    {"fileTrackingId":"83a86c44-66a5-4de0-9b7f-
    c6995877279d","name":"textfile_2017-08-21T15:58:45Z","fileType":
    {"code":"textfile"}},"eventTimestamp":"2017-08-
    21T15:59:30Z"}}},"operationName":"CreateFileReceivedEvent"}'
```

My scala code:
step1: copying the entire json string(pay load) to txt file

```
 '{"query":"mutation CreateFileReceivedEvent($createFileReceivedEventInput: 
    CreateFleReceivedEventInput!) {  createFileReceivedEvent(input: 
    $createFileReceivedEventInput) {    clientMutationId  }}","variables":
    {"createFileReceivedEventInput":
    {"clientMutationId":"Test","fileReceivedEvent":{"file":
    {"fileTrackingId":"83a86c44-66a5-4de0-9b7f-
    c6995877279d","name":"textfile_2017-08-21T15:58:45Z","fileType":
    {"code":"textfile"}},"eventTimestamp":"2017-08-
    21T15:59:30Z"}}},"operationName":"CreateFileReceivedEvent"}'
```

step2:

```
 val data=fromFile("/usr/test/data.txt").getLines.mkString
```

step3:

```
val cmd = Seq("curl", "http://laptpad1811:5000/graphql", "-H",
  "'Content-Type:application/json'" ,"-X", "POST", "-d" , data)
```

step4:

```
cmd.!!
```

I get the below error

```
String =
"{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Must provide query string.",
      "stack": "BadRequestError: Must provide query string.\n
```

I have tried to change " to ' and mutiple combinations of the json string but I always get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your issue is that sys.process doesn't pass commands through the shell (e.g. bash), so quotes that are necessary in the shell become unnecessary in Scala (and get passed through to the command which in the case of Unix-style utilities will probably result in unexpected behavior).

So try:

```
val cmd = Seq("curl", "http://laptpad1811:5000/graphql", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "POST", "-d", data)
```

Likewise remove the single quote wrapping from your text file.

I would however, counsel against spawning a curl in Scala and advise using one of the existing http client libraries (I personally like Gigahorse).

Comment: This worked. removing the quotes worked. Thanks Levi!!